# SMTP Implementation in java

Tags: java, email

I wrote a java  program to implement smtp.

My input consists of five arguments:
`localhost 25  localhost.com   loaclhost.com  "hellooo"`

I am getting the following error:

```
D:trying to connect to server
D:connected
D:response: 220 localhost ESMTP server ready.
D:sending command: HELO SRIJA-PC
D:response: 250 localhost Hello, SRIJA-PC.
D:sending command: MAIL from: localhost.com
D:response: 250 Sender OK - send RCPTs.
D:sending command: RCPT to: localhost.com
D:response: 553 Invalid RFC821 mailbox specification.
Error while sending: Error while executing cmd RCPT to: localhost.com:553-Invalid RFC821 mailbox specification.
```

Can you please help me to solve the error?

Comment: Why? JavaMail already exists. And where is your *code*?

Comment: In other words: read [mcve] and add the missing information to your question.

Comment: `localhost.com` is not an email address. An email address is something like `in.over.my.head@example.org`. <== Notice the `@` sign.

Comment: @anju mary .What excatly you want to implement. A mail functionality..??

Answer (score 0):

The `RCPT to:` command is supposed to contain the email address of the intended recipient, e.g. a.user@localhost.com, but you appear to have entered `RCPT to: localhost.com`.  See Section 3.3 of RFC 5321 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.3):

> The second step in the procedure is the RCPT command.  This step of
> the procedure can be repeated any number of times.
>
> ```
>   RCPT TO:<forward-path> [ SP <rcpt-parameters> ] <CRLF>
> ```
>
> The first or only argument to this command includes a forward-path
> (normally a mailbox and domain, always surrounded by "<" and ">" brackets) identifying one recipient.

"localhost.com" is not a valid email address, hence the mail server is replying with "Invalid RFC821 mailbox specification".

Answer (score 0):

The error message states, that your command `RCPT to: localhost.com` was faulty.
[RFC821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) ist the specification for the SMTP protocol.

The [error code `553`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821#page-35) represents the following:

```
553 Requested action not taken: mailbox name not allowed [E.g., mailbox syntax incorrect]
```

So you simply did not enter a correct recipient. Try to enter a full e-mail address which contains a `@` symbol.

This is a simple example taken from the [RFC821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821#page-51) showing how to send an e-mail correctly:

```
R: 220 BBN-UNIX.ARPA Simple Mail Transfer Service Ready
S: HELO USC-ISIF.ARPA
R: 250 BBN-UNIX.ARPA

S: MAIL FROM:<Smith@USC-ISIF.ARPA>
R: 250 OK

S: RCPT TO:<Jones@BBN-UNIX.ARPA>
R: 250 OK

S: RCPT TO:<Green@BBN-UNIX.ARPA>
R: 550 No such user here

S: RCPT TO:<Brown@BBN-UNIX.ARPA>
R: 250 OK

S: DATA
R: 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
S: Blah blah blah...
S: ...etc. etc. etc.
S: .
R: 250 OK

S: QUIT
R: 221 BBN-UNIX.ARPA Service closing transmission channel
```